# Getting "with clause can only reference columns in the driving table" when trying to write a JPA 2.1 left outer join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, left-join, jpa-2.0, criteria

I’m using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 4.3.6.Final.  I’m trying to use CriteriaBuilder to write a left outer join with conditions, so I have

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Message> query = cb.createQuery(Message.class);
Root<Message> messageRoot = query.from(Message.class);
final Join<Message, Group> groupJoin = messageRoot.join(Message_.group);
final Join<Message, MessageReadDate> msgReadDateJoin = messageRoot.join(Message_.messageReads, JoinType.LEFT);

// form left outer join clause.
msgReadDateJoin.on( cb.equal(messageRoot, msgReadDateJoin.get(MessageReadDate_.message)),
                    cb.equal(msgReadDateJoin.get(MessageReadDate_.recipient), recipient) );
```

Ultimately, this produces an exception when I run my query, which is below.  I don’t understand what the error message means, but more importantly, how do I rewrite my query (above) to achieve the same thing but cure this annoying exception?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidWithClauseException: with clause can only reference columns in the driving table [select generatedAlias0 from org.mainco.subco.myrpoject.domain.Message as generatedAlias0 inner join generatedAlias0.group as generatedAlias1 left join generatedAlias1.classroom as generatedAlias2 left join generatedAlias2.roster as generatedAlias3 left join generatedAlias0.messageReads as generatedAlias4 with ( generatedAlias0=generatedAlias4.message ) and ( generatedAlias4.recipient=:param0 ) where ( generatedAlias4.message is null ) and ( generatedAlias3.classroom=generatedAlias0.group.classroom ) and ( generatedAlias1.name=:param1 ) and ( generatedAlias3.user=:param2 ) and ( generatedAlias3.enabled=:param3 )]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker$WithClauseVisitor.visit(HqlSqlWalker.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.handleWithFragment(HqlSqlWalker.java:437)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3903)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3689)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:568)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.mainco.subco.myrpoject.repo.MessageDaoImpl.getUnreadClassAnnouncements(MessageDaoImpl.java:168)
    at org.mainco.subco.myrpoject.repo.MessageDaoImpl.getUnreadMessages(MessageDaoImpl.java:139)
    at org.mainco.subco.myrpoject.repo.MessageDaoIT.testCreateMessage(MessageDaoIT.java:319)
```

Answer (score 14):

Check https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2772 , looks like this is a bug in Hibernate. Try to use the primary keys (i.e., the IDs) instead of the object references in the ON clause

Comment: Hi Vic, you'd know a way in a QueryDSL environment ?